# Windows Bash won't open in 10 Anniversary Update

Tags: windows-10, command-line, bash, windows-10-v1607, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After I installed the Windows 10 Anniversary Update, I was eager to try the new Bash command prompt. But when launched from the start menu (Win+R -> bash.exe), the bash window closes automatically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For some reason it wasn't opening. But while I was writing this question I was able to find the answer so I decided to share it here if someone else had the same issue.

I decided to just start a shell prompt and type bash in it. The error message was about the "legacy mode enabled". To change it:

- right click on the cmd promt window.
- In option tab, uncheck the "Use legacy console"
- Apply the changes and restart cmd.exe
- type bash.

Installation will starts.

Enjoy!

Comment: From user [Shaun](http://superuser.com/users/641598/shaun): Had the same issue as above, solution worked, but also need to have developer mode enabled, go to settings>update and security, go to developers, and check developer mode checkbox. May require a restart after windows downloads and installs the package. Then run cmd again and execute bash, as per steps above, bash.exe will download and install.

Comment: Apparently no longer a solution because I now get, "Unsupported console settings. In order to use this feature the legacy console must be disabled.
Press any key to continue..."

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue as above, solution worked, but also need to have developer mode enabled, go to settings>update and security, go to developers, and check developer mode checkbox. May require a restart after windows downloads and installs the package. Then run cmd again and execute bash, as per steps above, bash.exe will download and install.

Comment: Welcome to Super User, and thanks for trying to help on this question.  In this Q&A format, answers are intended for complete solutions to the question, with each answer providing a solution substantially different from what has already been contributed.  Clarifications like this can go in a comment (requires a little more rep), or be proposed as an edit to the other answer.  "No good deed goes unpunished"; non-answers tend to attract downvotes or get deleted.  I went ahead and copied this to a comment for you so it doesn't get lost.  You might want to delete this post.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue after a reinstall of the bash command prompt. I had switched to another shell (zsh) and set it to autostart using my startup script. Since it wasn't installed after the reinstall of the bash component, opening the prompt failed. I used 'bash -c "nano "~/.bashrc"' entered into the standard Windows cmd prompt to edit it and then could start the shell again.