# Bash won't open in Windows 11

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-11

I am trying to open Bash in Windows 11. However, I can't get it to open. The best that happens is it opens and then immediately closes (in a fraction of a second).

I understand there is already a question posted regarding [opening bash in Win 10 Anniversary](https://superuser.com/questions/1112429/windows-bash-wont-open-in-10-anniversary-update). I tried those fixes, but they were not effective. Since Windows 11 has significant changes (especially compared to Win 10 feature updates), I argue that it deserves its own post.

The steps that I have taken:

1. Turn on developer mode (significantly different in Win 11. I followed this guide on [How to Enable Developer Mode in Windows 11](https://websiteforstudents.com/how-to-enable-developer-mode-in-windows-11/).
2. Turn on WSL (following this guide to [Enable Bash on Windows 10](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/08/enable-bash-windows-10-anniversary-update)) and start Bash.

I have gone through these steps several times, but had no success. In addition to following the instructions set out about, I have:

- Restarted my computer many, many, times.
- Uninstalled/reinstalled WSL from 'Turn Windows features on and off' several times.
- Tried the solution set out in the parent question (opening in Win 10) and tried enabling legacy console. I have tried with legacy on and off, without success.
- Tried typing the command (in CMD prompt), "bash". [Another post about Bash opening and closing](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/87340519-9a85-4b3d-8ed3-d73d345082bf/bash-on-windows-10-just-opens-and-closes) mentioned (first answer by '-Mr Happy') about typing "Bash" into CMD prompt. I tried that and CMD responded with "Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions. Distributions can be installed by visiting the Microsoft Store: https://aka.ms/wslstore". This took me to the Windows Store to install a program to "Run Linux on Windows". As such...
- I installed the Ubuntu app. I had no idea what this would accomplish, but I was happy to try anything at this stage. When opening the Ubuntu app, it just opens a shell window (not sure about terminology) which says "Press any key to continue..." (closes the window immediately). I don't know what this was supposed to do, but I basically uninstalled/reinstalled WSL just to check.
- Additional to -Mr Happy-'s advice above, he suggested to check the contents of the folder: C:\Users%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\lxss. At no point was the folder 'lxss' created. I imagine this is why bash.exe never worked. Nothing that I did caused the folder to be created.

All of this is to [install zsy on my computer](https://www.maketecheasier.com/install-zsh-and-oh-my-zsh-windows10/). I appreciate any advice on the matter.

Comment: Have you installed a distro through the windows/microsoft store?  Bash is not part of windows (even 11).  Bash comes with a distro (or multiple) that you install *through* WSL.  WSL does NOTHING on it's own but allow you to install Linux distros.  Don't give up!  WSL is b@d a$$!  :)

Comment: S**t.. I should have read your post better.  Your problem lies in getting a distro installed.  Try a different one.  I myself run ubuntu and debian with ZERO issues.  If that fails, you can skip the rest of your problems and jump right down to the fact that you can't get a distro to install from the ms store.

Comment: WSL hasn’t required Developer Mode be enabled for more than 3 years now.

Comment: @Ramhound, does that mean I can just switch it off without issues?

Comment: I know next to nothing about your system, what I can tell you, is that Developer Mode is NOT required for WSL on any supports version of Windows 10 or any version of Windows 11.

Answer (score 2):

In keeping with the [parent question](https://superuser.com/questions/1112429/windows-bash-wont-open-in-10-anniversary-update), through the assistance of [Señor CMasMas](https://superuser.com/users/1000631/se%C3%B1or-cmasmas), I may have found the solution to my own question.

Below is the journey that I took to reach the solution. Short version: [update to WSL2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-5---set-wsl-2-as-your-default-version) to enable Bash/Ubuntu/Debian.

1. I downloaded Debian. Debian didn't install, but it told me to go to [Docs: Install WSL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install).
2. Through a series of PowerShell code typed into CMD Prompt and various web searches, I stumbled upon the idea of changing to [WSL 2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-5---set-wsl-2-as-your-default-version).
3. In doing this, PowerShell informed me that I needed to [enable the virtual machine feature](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-3---enable-virtual-machine-feature).
4. Then, I returned back to change to WSL 2 (step 2 above) and then Bash/Ubuntu/Debian worked fine.

Thank you for your assistance.